# Polymer custom element dependencies

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Given the following:

```
<custom_element_a>
   <custom_element_b></custom_element_b>
</custom_element_a>
```

Suppose that `custom_element_b` must always be a direct child of `custom_element_a`, although `custom_element_a` can also live on its own.

Are there any best practices that should be followed when implementing custom elements having a dependency relationship such as the above? E.g. should `custom_element_b` be implemented in the same file as `custom_element_a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those cases the most common pattern I see is:

```
custom-element-a/
    custom-element-a.html
    custom-element-b.html
```

An example is `paper-item`, which also includes a `paper-item-body` and `paper-icon-item`: https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item

Comment: That sound likes a sensible approach